# Javascript multiply 3 inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, multiplication

I know this topic has been touched many times on here but I can't quite seem to get it right.  I'm pulling a value for #resultBox based on the dropdown that is selected.  Then I want to multiply that by the 2 input fields below.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

```
<input type="text" id="resultBox" name="resultBox" readonly="true" />
<select id="off" onchange="calc()">
    <option value="1" data-one="0" >Select Option</option>
    <option value="14" data-one="14" >Off</option>
    <option value="8" data-one="8" >On</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<!-- FTE -->
FTE
<div id="f1">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="FTE" id="FTE">
    </form>
</div>

<!-- Duration -->
Duration
<div id="d1">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="Duration" id="Duration">
    </form>
</div>

    <div id="dom_element">-</div>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
$('#off').change(function () {
    var select1_control = 1;
    var str = select1_control * $(this).find('option:selected').data('one');
    $('#resultBox').val(str);


});


  var multiplier = 1;

// bind keyup
 $("#FTE").on("keyup change", function() {
   var value = this.value;   
   var valuemath = value * durationMultiplier;  
    $("#dom_element").text(valuemath);   
});


$('#Duration').change(function(){
    durationMultiplier = $(this).val();
    $("#FTE").trigger("keyup");



});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xuC6f/50/

Comment: Read you some error console please

Comment: declare `var durationMultiplier = 0;` as first line in your JS

Comment: I was able to get it get it going through another route.

http://jsfiddle.net/xuC6f/66/

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
function calc(multiply)
{
    if (multiply) { tt.value = parseFloat(qt.value * un.value).toFixed(2); }
    else { un.value = parseFloat(tt.value / qt.value).toFixed(2); }
}

<form>
    <ul>
        <li>Qt: <input type="text" id="qt" onblur="calc(true)" /></li>
        <li>Unt: <input type="text" id="un" onblur="calc(true)" /></li>
        <li>Tot: <input type="text" id="tt" onblur="calc(false)" /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```